# Jenkins Job Failing - Overwrite to pass Yslow PhantomJS

Tags: jenkins, phantomjs, yslow

I have a build that calls Yslow test. The build fails due to some of the yslow tests fail (which I am aware of).

Is there a way to set it so Jenkins does not mark the build "failed" regardless of the yslow tests?

Shell:

```
/usr/local/bin/phantomjs yslow.js -i grade -t 50 -f junit http://www.website.com > yslow.xml
```

Console Output:

```
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Recording test results
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [groovyPostbuild](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) plugin for this.  Something like the following should work:

```
if(manager.logContains(".*Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure.*")) {
    manager.build.@result = hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS
}
```